# Preenchimento de campos

Tags: php

Tenho um formulário, em que ao digitar uma matrícula no campo matrícula, ele lista as matrículas. E cada matrícula é relacionada a uma pessoa e seus dados: nome, data de nascimento, data de admisssão.

Porém, preciso que quando eu clicar na matrícula, ele preencha os demais campos do formulário. E essa parte eu não estou conseguindo elaborar e executar.

Esse é o código que lista as matrículas:

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name
$username="teste_inezb"; // Mysql username
$password=""; // Mysql password
$db_name="teste_login"; // Database name


    $con = mysql_connect($host,$username,$password)   or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($db_name, $con)  or die(mysql_error());

$q = strtolower($_GET["q"]);
if (!$q) return;

$sql = "select DISTINCT MATRIC from DBWEBCAD where MATRIC LIKE '%$q%'";
$rsd = mysql_query($sql);
while($rs = mysql_fetch_array($rsd)) {
    $cmat = $rs['MATRIC'];
    $cname = $rs ['NOMSCODEP'];
    echo "$cmat\n", "$cname\n";
}
?>
```

Comment: Você quer trocar de página pra fazer isso ou continuar na mesma ?

Comment: Na mesma. A matrícula já é listada, só preciso que ela complete os campos necessários.

Comment: Não estou conseguindo entender muito bem qual é seu problema quais são as dificuldades que vc esta enfrentando. Vc poderia ser mais especifica?

Comment: Editei a pergunta

Comment: @InezBoldrin você terá que criar outra função que ao clicar em cima da matrícula, preencha os campos. Isso pode ser feito com JS, AJAX.

Comment: Boa tarde @InezBoldrin, uma recomendação fora do escopo da sua pergunta: do jeito que está seu código, ele está vulnerável a [SQL Injection](http://www.zoomdigital.com.br/sql-injection-o-que-e-e-como-evitar/). Tanto que esta função `mysql_query` foi [depreciada](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) pelo PHP. Sugiro usar outras alternativas como [Mysqli](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.mysqli.php) ou [PDO](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/ref.pdo-mysql.php), e usar conceitos como `prepare statements`, por exemplo.

Comment: Quanto a sua pergunta, acredito que você queira fazer uma requisição para o servidor depois da página carregada, para buscar um dado que surgiu a partir da interação com o usuário (no caso, a matrícula). Isto? Este processo no javascript é chamado de AJAX, e envolve criar um script do lado do cliente em javacript e um script em PHP para retornar estes dados (em forma de JSON, por exemplo). De qualquer forma, você teria que nos mostrar sua implementação atual HTML/JS para entendermos melhor seu problema. Abraços.

Comment: Então, eu fiz umas pesquisas e vi sobre o Ajax, JSON porém, eu não sei elaborar um código com eles. Vocês possuem algum vídeo mais explicativo?

Comment: @InezBoldrin você já conhece alguma coisa de `JavaScript`? Se não, recomendo aprender os fundamentos desta linguagem. Depois, você pode estudar [jQuery](https://jquery.com/), uma biblioteca bem famosa, que facilita bastante a vida de quem trabalha com js (em linhas gerais, trabalha em cima do javascript, mas torna-o mais fácil - principalmente para quem está iniciando e não quer se aprofundar em javascript puro -, e mais compatível seu código  - você não precisa escrever coisa diferentes para outros browsers). Dentro do jQuery existem métodos para obter o que você deseja aqui (`$.ajax`).

Comment: Quanto a aulas, eu não estou muito por dentro. Mas recomendo procurar no Youtube, tem muita gente boa lá.

Answer (score 3):

Posso te dar um caminho assim. Imagine que você tenha os campos HTML na página e a lista de matrículas, com uma classe chamada `numero_matricula`.

### HTML

```
<li id="mat123" class="numero_matricula"> 123 </li>
<li id="mat231" class="numero_matricula"> 231 </li>
<li id="mat321" class="numero_matricula"> 321 </li>

<input type="text" id="nome">
<input type="text" id="idade">
<input type="text" id="email">
```

Ao clicar em alguma matrícula a classe chamará a função debaixo que irá chamar uma página por AJAX que irá fazer a busca dos dados em PHP.

### JS - jQuery

```
$(document).on('click', 'li.numero_matricula', function(){
   var matricula = $(this).attr('id').replace('mat', '');
   $.ajax({
      type: POST,
      url: 'pagina.php',
      data: { mat: mat },
      success: function(result){
         $('#nome').val(result.nome);
         $('#idade').val(result.idade);
         $('#email').val(result.email);
      }
   })
});
```

A página que faz a busca é essa. Bem simples, um `SELECT`buscando os dados do usuário pelo número da matrícula vindo por `POST` da função `AJAX` acima.
O resultado é convertido em `JSON` e imputado nos campos.

### PHP

**`pagina.php`**

```
$mat = $_POST['mat'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE numero_matricula = $mat";
$arrDados = json_encode(mysql_fetch_array($query));
return $arrDados;
```